# JetBrains Rider import reference inside namespace

Tags: jetbrains-ide, rider

We have a style rule that requires 'using' statements be 'inside' a namespace declaration in a class.
I cannot find where to set my automatic references from the code editor so that any 'using' statements which are added will be inside the namespace rather than at the top of the page.
In Settings there is Code Style | C# | Code Style | Reference Qualification but those settings do not deal with placement in the file.

Is this possible, where?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the answer @ https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360001334920-Optimize-imports-add-reference-option-to-put-using-directives-inside-namespace

File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | C# | Code Style | Reference Qualification | Add 'using' directive to deepest scope

Comment: In Rider 2021 it's: File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | C# | Syntax Style | Reference Qualification and 'using' Directives | Add 'using' directive to deepest scope